# GTA V graphics bugs on PS3

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-v

I just started playing GTA V on my PS3 and during gameplay I noticed that somewhere around the middle-left corner of the screen these strange gray/blackish rectangles keep showing up...they are kinda like flashing in and out very quickly...the rectangles/shapes are not always identical, but they keep showing up in the middle-left corner of the screen.

The rectangles seem to show up especially during daytime in the game. Maybe someone has had the same problem? What would be a fix for this? I have had similar kind of problem in Batman Arkham City, but there workaround for this was simply to restart the game. I tried this also on GTA V and for one time it seemed to work, but couldn't really confirm this yet.

I managed to take the screenshots when the glitch happens. You can see them here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttv7g.jpg

Here you can see a youtube-video of the problem:

Any ideas? Similar experiences?

**UPDATE**

It seems I'm having similar troubles as posted here:

[PS3 graphics Stretching Glitch](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81253/ps3-graphics-stretching-glitch)

It might be my GPU failing...I'm having similar issues in different games...some less, some more...for example in Killzone 3, Batman Arkham City and GTA 5..

What would be my best action? Buy a new PS3 or change for example the thermal paste on my PS3 and do thorough dust cleaning?...I tried setting my PS3 to fridge for 30 mins and tried playing and the problem went away...for 10-15 minutes :/ It seems the PS3 gets too hot...

**UPDATE 2**

I just want to add here that I tried cleaning the PS3, but it didn't help, so I bought a new one and the problem got fixed! So the problem was the old PS3.

Comment: Remember the mission, where you first meet Michael? After the mission is done, you'll be at Simeon's as Michael. Don't move, just rotate the camera a bit. Objects will turn invisible and black & grey surfaces/triangles will show up. This game has so many optimizations in order to look good, that bugs were bound to happen at some point. The game is still very playable, though.

Comment: It looks to me that it is just a graphics engine glitch, does it always happen or just in that one location?

Comment: @ColeBusby It randomly happens here and there and it is not always exactly the same. But it does happen often and on the same spot on the screen...at least so far.

Comment: @Nolonar okay so this is unfixable glitch? :)

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the shader to generate the shadow, if you move out of the shadow do you still get this?

Comment: @DogDog I'm not quite sure I think yes, it does happen randomly. During cutscenes, gameplay...but it has always happened during daylight in the game..

Comment: @jjepsuomi It's probably fixable through a patch, but I doubt Rockstar will make one :(

Comment: @Nolonar okay :/ Thnx for your reply :) I submitted this problem to Rockstars support page. Hope they notice it and include a fix for this in the next update.

Comment: Is this disc based game or downloadable copy? (I read that ps3 had same day download copy)

Comment: @ColeBusby A disc based game.

Comment: @DogDog I tested again if I go out of the sun I couldn't get the problem, but when I ran to the sunlight I could get similar glimpses of it again when I was close to a shadow...might be the shader you suggested :) During night in the game this doesn't happen. At least not yet...

Comment: Yeh I remember when I did shaders at school, I had some similar issues sometimes =) doing shadows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could as already stated be a sign of a hardware issue in the PS3 itself, However don't overlook the possibility of it being a television problem. Try hooking up to another tv, and if that does not fix the problem there may even be something up with the AV or HDMI cable you are using. if swapping out these things does not help and you are still under a warranty I would recommend downloading all your save files to flash drives and return the ps3 for a new one.

as for the heat problem try to keep your PS3 in a well ventilated area. if this does not help it is more than likely either due to some sort of heat sensor problem or something to do with the fans.